# Should you ask a stranger in your shul if he is Jewish?

Tags: halacha, gentiles, synagogue, minyan, social-convention

We've had a few questions similar to [this one](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/64601/5275) that deal with assuming that you have a minyan, when in fact you don't.

Shuls are, generally, open to anyone. We usually assume that when a stranger enters the shul, and you have nine people, you are thrilled to see that tenth male coming in so you have your minyan. I'm unaware that any rabbai, gabbai, or anyone else in the shul even thinks to ask the stranger: "Are you Jewish?" (Maybe Chabad does this? They ask me on the subway if I'm Jewish — as if my Mets cap doesn't answer the question!)

In light of the possibility that the tenth man, may, in fact, *not* be Jewish, is there a halachic requirement to inquire? If so, what would be a good way to approach such a stranger without offending him?

**Note:** If it were a weekday Shacharit, I guess if you saw that he wasn't wearing a tallit or tefillin, that *might* be a hint, but not necessarily. One Jewish man in my shul attends daily minyan but never wears tefillin.

Comment: I've heard one approach to the "how" that works on torah-reading days (but not others): ask if he is a kohein, levi, or yisrael.  I don't remember where I heard this.  As a stranger showing up on a weekday I was once asked if I had a yahrzeit.

Comment: For Chabad, they assume, unless they are informed otherwise, that anyone who goes into one of their schuls is Jewish.

Comment: As [suggested elsewhere](/a/33685), a gentile attending services where there is barely a _minyan_ should tell the rabbi or _gabay_ (person in charge of making sure the services run smoothly) that he's not Jewish, so that he doesn't get counted toward a _minyan_.

Comment: Once you're about it, why not worry that he doesn't keep Shabbos: וְכָל הַמְחַלֵּל אֶת הַשַׁבָּת בְּפַרְהֶסְיָא, הֲרֵי הוּא כְּעוֹבֵד כּוֹכָבִים לְכָל דְּבָרָיו

Comment: @MonicaCellio http://yodeya.com/a/47970

Comment: "ah! are you going to complete our minyan?"

Comment: @DanF - Quote is from Kitzur Shulchan Aruch סימן עב - גדל קדשת שבת והמחללו הרי הוא כמו עובד כוכבים - http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00561.html#HtmpReportNum0071_L2

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt I think most people, not just chabad would assume any person walking into shul is jewish, certainly I would. Unless there is a reason to assume he is not. From my experiences in chabad they try to find out without being obvious. I am not saying what one should do just my experience.

Comment: In regards to them asking you on the subway if you are jewish that is for mivtzoim. They go around on Fridays and before holidays and try to find random people on the street to talk to and teach about judiasim, put on tefilin(for men) give shabbos candles.

Comment: @mroll Hang around Fri. afternoon in the Atlantic Ave. / Barclay's Center "alleyway" in the NYC subway system. It's fascinating. They "compete" with at least one other preacher / Catholic group.

Comment: Strangers walking into a synagogue might not know anything about the minyan nor understand it if someone verbally celebrates that a tenth person has come in and now they have a minyan.  The responsibility to report one is not Jewish should not rest on the visitor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There would seem to be a chazakah that someone who enters a shul to daven is Jewish, especially if you see them davening.

This is no worse than the chazakah that someone who comes to Yerushalayim to eat the korban Pesach is assumed to be Jewish (until proven otherwise as in the case of Bava ben Buta).

If they are not Jewish, at worst you have been over an issur de'rabanan of saying borchu, birchas ha'torah etc. without a minyan. In the case of the korban pesach you would be over a deoraisah (kol ben nechar lo yochal bo etc.).

So kal ve'chomer we assume the minyan is Jewish.

Comment: I see some practical problems with the implications of your 1st sentence. My shul has become a community "warming hut" for some homeless people. On a few occasions, we have had strangers walk into shul  while we were davening and sit themselves in a back row and not daven. The gabbai and rabbi, to some degree, figures that a man wearing torn jeans a torn coat and checkered shirt on Shabbat is prob. non Jewish. That's a poor way to determine someone's status, IMO. Similarly, someone well-dressed who prays from a Burnbaum prayer book in English can also be non-Jewish, even though he is praying.

Comment: As this bounty is about to expire, and you have the only answer, I am awarding the bounty. Your answer is credible, though, I would like to see it strengthened, at least with some link to sources. Also, see the above comment. I realize that what I mentioned may not have been a concern at the time of the ruling, but, it may be a practical issue, now. Perhaps, at some point, I'll need to edit my question and put up another bounty; just to gain more interest and better answers. Thanks for your post. Kol Tuv.