# Waiting for someone to finish prayer at Torah reading

Tags: tefilla, torah-reading, minyan

Consider a minyan of exactly 10 adult males. When they are about to remove the Torah from the ark, they realise that one of their friends is still is in his silent prayer. Can they proceed with the Torah reading or should they wait for him to finish? The Mishnah Berurah (33) to [Orach Chayim 55:6](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%95) cites the Peri Megadim that it needs further consideration. Do you know sources which have addressed this case since then?

Comment: Related question with 9 Jews: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/64668/15256

Answer (score 1):

The Mishnah Berura himself in [146:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Biur_Halacha.146.2.2?lang=bi) discusses it further and determines that sleeping wouldn’t work, but if someone is in middle of prayer, and stops and listens, it would work;

> ולא מיבעיא לדעת הט"ז וסייעתו בסימן נ"ה סק"ד דישן וכן מדבר ואינו שומע אינו מצטרף לענין תפלה משום דבעינן עשרה דצייתי וכדברי הרא"ש המובא בסימן קכ"ד ס"ד בודאי גם הכא בעינן עשרה דצייתי למה שקורא בספר ואין להתיר במה שעוסק באותו ענין דהא הט"ז שם כתב דגם בההיא דסעיף ו' דעסוק ג"כ בענין תפלה **אינו מותר רק משום דיכול להפסיק ולשתוק ושומע כעונה** אלא אפילו להשו"ע שם דמקיל אפשר הוא דוקא בתפלה ולא בקריאת התורה דשם בעינן דוקא צבור [ותדע דהא בעניני התפלה אחד מקבץ עשרה בני אדם אף שכבר התפללו ויצאו ידי ברכו וקדושה ועובר לפני התיבה ואומר ברכו וקדושה והכל עונין אחריו ולא מצינו כן בקריאת התורה שאחד שלא שמע קה"ת יוכל לקבץ עשרה שכבר קראו ולקרות עוד הפעם בשבילו (ועיין בסימן קמ"ב בבה"ל) וע"כ דלא נתקנה אלא בצבור דוקא] ובאמת ע"כ מוכרחין אנו לומר כן לדעת השו"ע דקה"ת חמיר טפי דהא בעניננו מבואר להדיא בבה"ג ורי"ף דבעינן עשרה דצייתי ולא מצטרף במה שאחד יושב ועוסק אפילו בד"ת ולדעת השו"ע שם הלא מצטרף במה שיושב שם בביהכ"נ לחוד וכמבואר שם במגן אברהם סק"ח וע"כ דקריאה חמירא טפי [**ומזה באמת נפשט ספיקא דפמ"ג שהבאתי לעיל במ"ב סימן נ"ה סקל"ג שמסתפק לענין קה"ת אם ישן מהני ומדברי בה"ג ורי"ף משמע דלא מהני**]

Comment: It happened on the Shabbat, but even on a weekday isn't it a problem that he would wait more than duration of his prayer?

Comment: I guess between aliyos he can continue so it’s not one long hefsek.

Comment: A second question from my friend: How do we know that he has stopped and is listening? For a short pause, like the priestly blessing it is fine, but for a Torah reading...